# How to pass through a separate parameter through the Camera intent in android

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, arguments, bundle

I'm creating a dynamic form activity and I get the instructions on how to make the forms from a db. The activity essentially just scrolls the list of questions and sees what type they are and adds them. So it's an activity that adds a view as a question. That all works fine by itself. I tried to keep the responses/questions inside the specific question classes which just subclass a base question.

The problem I'm having is when I try to add a camera "question" to prompt the user to take a picture, I can't get the result inside the view. I managed the launch the activity in the view, and it returns the result to the questionnaire activity. The activity doesn't know which question it's meant to add it to, since it's all done dynamically. So I tried passing through the questionId through as an extra in the camera intent and receive it in the questionnaire activity where it then scrolls through the questions it's added and if it's the same one, it adds the picture to the question it's associated to.

The way it adds questions is by having a viewgroup which just inserts at a part for each of them.

This the relevant part that launches the camera (I've tried using it without a bundle, too). **This is inside a subclass of a BaseQuestion which is just a subclass of a linearlayout**:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("questionId", getQuestionId());
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new File(
                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "image.tmp")));
            ((Activity)getContext()).startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PHOTO);
```

This is the relevant part that handles the result which is in an activity.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);
    Bitmap image = null;
    switch (requestCode) 
    {
        case TAKE_PHOTO: 
        {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
            {
                InputStream inputStream = null;
                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                        "image.tmp");
                try {
                    inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (inputStream == null) {
                    Uri uri = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                    try {
                        inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                image = createScaledBitmapFromStream(inputStream, 200, 300);
                Bundle bundle = imageReturnedIntent.getExtras();
                if (bundle != null)
                {
                    int questionId = bundle.getInt("questionId");
                    for (BaseQuestion questionView : questionViews)
                    {
                        if (questionId == questionView.getQuestionId())
                        {
                            questionView.setResponse(image);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } 
            else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) 
            {
                Log.d("something", "something");
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT: Solved, might not be clear from answer**

I made questionIdForResult in my superclass which I set to -1. I then set it to the questionId when it runs startActivityForResult, and then in onActivityResult, I check each question if their questionIdForResult matches their questionId and if it does, use that one. I then set it back to -1 to make sure if you have two, it doesn't go to the other one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your approach will not work, as there is no requirement for any camera app to magically copy extras from the incoming `Intent` to the result `Intent`. In fact, I will be rather surprised if any camera activity does this.

You could store `questionId()` in a data member of the activity (e.g., `questionIdForTheNextActivityResult`), then use that value in `onActivityResult()`. Bear in mind, though, that taking a picture using a third-party app means that your process may be terminated before you get control again, so be sure to save that data member via `onSaveInstanceState()` and restore it via `onRestoreInstanceState()`.

Comment: How would I pass it through though? It sounds like you're suggesting to just store the variable as a global value in the activity. I still have the problem of passing it back to the activity without prior knowledge of the id. When coming back from the camera, how do I pass it back?

Comment: @Gentatsu: "I still have the problem of passing it back to the activity without prior knowledge of the id" -- if you have enough "knowledge of the id" to put it in an extra of an `Intent` used with `startActivity()`, you have enough "knowledge of the id" to simply hold onto it in the activity in a data member.

Comment: It knows all the ids of each question when creating it, but it doesn't know what's happening inside them. The activity just acts as a container. It's going CameraQuestionView -> CameraActivity -> QuestionnaireActivity. If it went back to the CameraQuestionView, I'd be fine with it. The activity's holding all the ids, and it can't differentiate between which one to add the information to, I just need a way of telling it which one it needs to go to.

I'm sorry if I'm sounding rude, but it's quite frustrating trying to get what I'm trying to say across coherently enough.

Comment: I've found that you could add information into the physical file itself, such as the description of the image, but I'd like to avoid that, if possible. I'd also like to avoid having it as an SP, or anything else that is available globally in the app. I'm looking for a good approach, not just a quick and dirty fix.

Comment: @Gentatsu: "The activity just acts as a container" -- then you will need to give the container more intelligence, or use a more intelligent container (e.g., a fragment, rather than a custom view). "it can't differentiate between which one to add the information to" -- you act like you have a choice. You do not. The implementer of `onActivityResult()`, whether that be an activity or fragment, needs to have, on its own, everything need to process that response. It is the implementer of `onActivityResult()` that is responsible for the `startActivityForResult()` call in the first place.

Comment: @Gentatsu: Now, you are welcome to say that `onActivityResult()` of your activity just calls a method on your custom view to tell it "um, something happened, here you go", where the custom view then handles it. But somewhere, at the point when you call `startActivityForResult()`, you need to store, in a data member somewhere, the ID of your question, so that when `onActivityResult()` is called, you have that ID. And, you need to ensure that this value survives process termination, via the saved instance state `Bundle`, particularly since you are launching the camera.

Comment: Goddamn it, how have I been so dumb?! I figured out what you meant before. I made questionIdForResult in my superclass which I set to -1. I then set it to the questionId when it runs startActivityForResult, and then in onActivityResult, I check each question if their questionIdForResult matches their questionId and if it does, use that one. I then set it back to -1 to make sure if you have two, it doesn't go to the other one. Thanks a lot!